# Magento Bug with additional checkbox in register field

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, checkbox

I have small issue with my two checkbox's. They work fine, but i find small bug. They are required to pass registration. If i don't check them both, information about requiment showing under second two times, if i chceck second, dont check first, information still showing under second. I trying to make more space between them by adding some break rows "", but it still happens. I showing a image of my problem, because im not perfect in english and it will help a lot. Red ring showing a issue.[image]

```
</br>
<input type="checkbox" id="regulaminsklepu" name="TEST1" value="1" title="" class="checkbox required-entry"> <i>„Oświadczam, iż zapoznałem/zapoznałam się z treścią Regulaminu Serwisu Internetowego WWW.WARM-IT.PL. Akceptuję treść ww. Regulaminu i zobowiązuję się do jego przestrzegania.”</i></br></br>
<input type="checkbox" id="pdane" name="TEST1" value="1" title="" class="checkbox required-entry"> <i>„Wyrażam zgodę na przetwarzanie moich danych osobowych przez Warm IT z siedzibą w Libiążu, na potrzeby i w zakresie niezbędnym do korzystania przeze mnie ze sklepu WWW.WARM-IT.PL, w tym na przekazywanie moich danych osobowych podmiotom trzecim, przy pomocy których Warm IT z siedzibą w Libiążu świadczy na moją rzecz usługi w ramach ww. sklepu.”</i>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have these checkboxes to be required just remove the css-class "required-entry" from the elements.

Comment: but i need to have it required. I have bug like this. If i dont find a solution, i just gonna put all in one checkbox.

Comment: So then I don't really understand your problem. What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding:

It is not a bug as you defined the 2 checkboxes as members of the same checkboxgroup, having the same name "TEST1", but both are required (not only one).

So magento places the validation result below the checkboxgroup.

Please try to give the 2 checkboxes different names so they are not a checkboxgroup but 2 separate checkboxes with own validation result below each checkbox.

Example:

```
...id="regulaminsklepu" name="TEST1" ... class="checkbox required-entry" ...
...id="pdane" name="TEST2" class="checkbox required-entry" ...
```